# Assumptions required for expected value of sum of products to equal zero.

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation, least-squares

First define $x_i$ is determenistic variable, $v_i$ is random variable. Consider the expression:

$$\text E(\sum_{i=1}^{\ n} x_iv_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{\ n} \text E (x_iv_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\ n} \text E (x_i) \text E(v_i) \text +{cov}(x_i,v_i)= E(x')E(v)+cov(x,v)\space \space \space \space \space \space = x'E(v)$$

Now, let's say we want to define the minimal assumption required so that the expression is zero. We can impose a restriction that $E(v_i)$= 0. However, I believe that it is too strong of a restriction to say ALL elements of $v_i$ have to have an expected value of 0. The problem here is that this can get quite complicated as the answer depends on the values of x. But, the question still remains, is there a comprehensive way to formulate the minimal condition so that the expression equals zero?

This applies to the OLS estimator, as in its derivation of bias it's assumed that a similar expression is zero if $\text E(v_i)=0$. However, I believe the assumption is too strict.

Comment: $x_i$ is deterministic, and you write $E(x_i)$ ? Something looks wrong here

Comment: @leonbloy Well, the expected value of $x_i$ is $x_i$. I suppose I should have removed the sign somewhere there...

Comment: But then it's way  simpler:  $E(\sum  x_i v_i) =\sum  x_i E(v_i)$. I don't understand why you deal with covariances. The covariance of a a deterministic value and a random variable is always zero.

Comment: @leonbloy It's still not very simple...

Comment: @leonbloy Edited now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already written the condition: letting $ {\bf \mu} = E( {\bf v})$ you must have $ {\bf x}' {\bf \mu} =0$, i.e, the inner product must be zero, i.e., the expected value of $ {\bf v}$ should be orthogonal to ${\bf x}$.

Comment: is there a way to write the orthogonality assumption using expected value or covariance operators or something else?

Comment: That's written using expected value (of $v$). Covariances have nothing to do here - if $x$ is a constant.

Comment: I suppose so... Still wondering why the OLS conditions are not written in this form, since it's the correct one. Thanks for the answer in any case.